# Bash file to set password for phone number in telegram cli

Tags: bash, command, command-line-interface, telegram

When you login by your phone number, you can set password for that phone number using telegram cli command `set_password <hint>`. After pressing enter it will ask for `new password:`, Also after entering pass and press enter it will ask for `retype new password:` and after filling that password will set.

Overview:

```
$ Execute ./telegram-cli for specific profile
....//Initializing  
>set_password hint
new password: xxx
retype new password: xxx
>quit
$
```

Now I want to write a bash script to do the job but the problem is prompts. I tried something like below with no success:

```
#!/bin sh
./telegram-cli command for specific profile << EOF
set_password hint
#What do I have to do to enter password after prompt?
```

As you know because I am in telegram cli command mode there is no commands like  `sleep`, `read` or something else.
Tell me if more information needed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @ScottMermelstein thanks but I'm looking for a way without expect, is it possible?

Comment: In my experience, no.  You can write your own C program and execute it in bash, telling it what to look for and what to respond, but that's basically what `expect` does for you.

Comment: Thanks again, Am I have to remove this question?

Comment: This is Stack Overflow.  If the question deserves to be removed, there are plenty of people who will vote to remove it.  :-)  The question isn't an invalid one, and you're not receiving downvotes, so the general rule is to leave the question up.  Even if it's a duplicate, someone may find your question first and be helped by it.

Comment: There is a way to do it by PHP with `proc_open` function, but for doing it in bash maybe the `Expect` is an answer